# How can I find an inexpensive studio or 1bdrm apartment in a safe, clean area?

Tags: rent, housing, frugal

I live in the Greater Seattle area and will be moving this summer. I am trying to cut expenses by moving to an inexpensive area but each time that I've found an inexpensive area and check Google Street View, it's a dirty, run down place.

Things I've tried:

- Roommates (5 of them for most of the last decade...)
- Look farther from the city (up to an hour commute)

How can I find an inexpensive place to live that is in a safe and clean area?

Comment: "I am trying to cut expenses by moving to an expensive area" Do you mean "inexpensive area"? It's at least possible you DO mean "expensive area", as you may then be able to cut down on transportation costs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with your coworkers who are at your approximate salary range, and are also single. They will know of neighborhoods, streets, and complexes that are in your price range. You may be able to also ask those  co-workers that were recently in your salary range because hopefully the places they lived have not changed that much.

While Street View helps in some respects, it doesn't tell you everything.

Comment: Huge +1 for asking co-workers for leads. Best deal I ever got on housing was renting from a co-worker's father... not because he cut me a special deal (though he was delighted by having a single professional as a tenant), but because the place was a bit of a white elephant, huge but only two tiny legal bedrooms. (In this area, to be advertised as a bedroom there must be a closet... surprising since historically I would have expected wardrobes as furniture to be considered equivalent.)